# Alternative solution for session in RESTful API

Tags: rest, api, session

**Scenario:**

I am developing an API for a booking system, where user (without registration) gets a quote (with price) for a service, then later uses that quote to place a booking with additional information.

**Question**

How do I verify a quote generated by a request (eg, QT001) won't be used by anyone else request. For example, anyone can randomly guess a quote id and request a booking for that. How do I verfiy the second request, that will be for booking, is from the same user who sent the request for quote.

Sorry if the context isn't clear enough, since I'm new to the RESTful API world.

Comment: this can be done by using authorization tokens. based on the token you can identify the users identity. this way you can check who sent the request.

Comment: @Redan well I thought of the same solution, can you provide some references for it. Since users won't be registered ones, how would I generate a token for them? And, should token be just random plain text or encrypted with anything else like (API key or something else)

Comment: curious question, why are you not registering the users? tokens will secure your APIs. 
i used this tutorial to better understand token based authentication http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: Well forcing users to register just to get a quote will add an additional step, so to reduce it, users won't need to register for that. I'm curious how do we generate access token without registering a user.

Comment: i think you can generate a unique ID for the quotes. your api will return { UniqueID: 1, Name: QT001} then the front end will use that unique ID to call another API. in c#, there's a GUID function that can generate a string that can be your uniqueID. in this way you will NOT use tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with cookies, then:

1. When a quote is created, the server should set a cookie with a key like "Quote" and the quote id as the value (e.g. QT001)
2. When a booking is requested, the server gets the cookie value for Quote and compares it with the quote id for which the user is requesting a booking
3. If someone is just guessing the quote id, then there will not be a match

Comment: But restful architecture doesn't suggest to keep state. Won't that violate how restful api should work.

Comment: Perhaps you could figure whether you need statelessness for your situation. For example, if you are using a load balancer, then the cookie solution won't work. If you really need everything in the request, then you could 1) When quote is created, return a token to user 2) Save the token quote id mapping in the server DB 3) User request for booking should have quote id and token 4) When server receives request for booking compare the quote id and token in the request against the DB. If its a match then continue

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @rameshpa. Actually I used the same approach you've just suggested and for the time being its working fine for me. I misunderstood the concept of authorization token & verification token, which made the situation tough. Thanks again.